Antisymmetric Structure Constants, $f_{ijk}$ of su(N) for generalised Gell-man/Pauli Matrices, $k$ is unique for a given $i,j$
I want to prove that for a fixed $(i,j)$ there exists only a single $k$ such that $f_{ijk} \neq 0$.
I did this by considering the Generalized Pauli matrices:
$$
\hat{T}_{\alpha_{nm}}=\frac{\hbar}{2}(|m\rangle\langle n|+|n\rangle\langle m|), \\
\hat{T}_{\beta_{nm}}=-i\frac{\hbar}{2}(|m\rangle\langle n|-|n\rangle\langle m|), \\
\hat{T}_{\gamma_{n}}=\frac{\hbar}{\sqrt{2n(n-1)}}\Big(\sum_{l=1}^{n-1}|l\rangle\langle l|+(1-n)|n\rangle\langle n|)\Big),
$$
where
$$
\alpha_{nm}=n^2+2(m-n)-1, \\
\beta_{nm}=n^2+2(m-n), \\
\gamma_{nm}=n^2-1. \\
$$
I then consider the possible commutations of these matrices with each other, for example (ignoring factors)
$$
[T_{\alpha_{nm}}, T_{\gamma_{u}}] = f_{ijk}T_{\beta_{nm}}.
$$
This is for the case when $n > u \geq m$. In all the results I find that when the matrices do not commute that there is not a linear combination of the generalised matrices but only a single matrix multiplied by some constant (the structure constant). Is this a good enough proof of the above statement?
Also if this is the case then why is are commutation relations defined with a summation in the first place?
